# SSRS Express 2012 - The specified report server URL could not be found

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-express

I know several similar questions to this have been posted, but I've walked through each of the provided solutions and nothing seems to resolve this issue...

I have SQL Express 2012 installed, and have created a simple report and want to deploy it to my local Report Manager website.  Every time I try to deploy it from VS, I'm getting an error message that says "The specified Report Server URL "http:///Reports_SQLEXPRESS" could not be found.  Verify the syntax of the URL and that the report server exists.

I'm able to browse this URL in my browser no problem; I've also confirmed through Reporting Services Configuration Manager that the URL and Virtual Directory are correct.  As far as I can see this should be working...

Does anyone have any advice for next steps so i can deploy this report?  I looked into it at the MSDN site and confirmed that the SQL Express w/ advanced tools should have this functionality... any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
"http://machine name/reportserver_sqlexpress"
```

is what my research has lead me to.

HTH